# Android stopping periodic work manager in background

Tags: android, kotlin, android-workmanager

I'm using periodic work manager for send local data to server, when application doesn't work.
It works perfectly on mine *Google Pixel*, but it stopping on *Arma* or *Xiaomi* devices, let's some code:

```kotlin
val tag = BackgroundSyncWorker.TAG
val workManager = WorkManager.getInstance(context)

val period = if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    DEBUG_BACKGROUND_WORKER_PERIOD
} else {
    BACKGROUND_WORKER_PERIOD
}

val request = PeriodicWorkRequest.Builder(
    BackgroundSyncWorker::class.java,
    period,
    TimeUnit.MINUTES,
    1,
    TimeUnit.MINUTES
).addTag(tag)
    .build()

workManager.enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(tag, ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, request)
```

And constans:

```kotlin
val DEBUG_BACKGROUND_WORKER_PERIOD = 15L
const val BACKGROUND_WORKER_PERIOD = 60L
```

When application started that code was invoked and application has been closed, when we loked at worker database, it contains scheduled work:
[image]
[image]

And than I've await about 40 minutes and nothing was happend (worker has notification, when it started), but when I launch the application worker start works immediately

Comment: On Xiaomi devices, battery optimization may kill the background process. Advise your users to configure the battery optimization so that it does not kill your app.

Comment: @Rediska is it possible to use alarm manager instead?

Comment: @syncended AlarmManager also can be killed by battery optimization

Answer (score 0):

Use: **adb shell dumpsys jobscheduler**

Check the dump and see what is Unsatisfied:

```
Required constraints: TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY [0x90000000]
  Satisfied constraints: DEVICE_NOT_DOZING BACKGROUND_NOT_RESTRICTED WITHIN_QUOTA [0x3400000]
  Unsatisfied constraints: TIMING_DELAY CONNECTIVITY [0x90000000]
```

Check also your bucket:

Standby bucket: RARE

If you are in a RARE bucket you might be battery optimized. Which means less time to execute your work per 24 hours. This is represented as QUOTA.  But you can check also what time you have used. Go to the sections:

**QuotaController** and you will see something like this for your app process id:

```
#{pdid}/1338805651 from {pdid}
    ACTIVE, within quota, 600000ms remaining in quota
```

Also, it might mean less Network Connectivity. Which is represented as CONNECTIVIY. Unfortunatelly if you have no network or not the right type - you will see the same as Unsatisfied. It is a little bit confusing.

Also ask the user to exempt you from battery optimization:

https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby#support_for_other_use_cases

And also check this site why everything is just unreliable:

https://dontkillmyapp.com/

Here are also some ideas on how to improve per each vendor.